# Measure time of json_encode and return json object and timer to AJAX

Tags: php, json, ajax

I need to measure the time of a json_encode operation and then return the value together with the json object without decoding it. How can I make this happen?

The code I have at the moment is:

```
$start2 = microtime(true);
$all = json_encode(array(iterator_to_array($cursor),$timeExecuted));
$end2 = microtime(true);
$result = ($end2-$start2);
echo $all;
```

How can I return $all and $result without decoding the json object?

Comment: Return it? Like `return $all`?

Comment: Then `return [ "all" => $all, "result" => $result ]` ?

Comment: But in my ajax I can only deal with one returned data. If I return $result after $all, the $all is overlooked. I need to include them both in one return without decoding the json object.

Comment: The `return [ "all" => $all, "result" => $result ]` doesn't seem to work. It doesnt return anything.

Comment: Ok. Lets take a step back. You show some code in PHP here, and imply (but not state) that this will be delivered to the client side via ajax (this is important). So when you say "return" you actually mean "sent to client" which is a significant distinction. You need to be sure you're using clear language when stating the problem.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I will try to explain it better. This PHP is called to via AJAX and I need to return/send back (not sure what the difference is..) data to my AJAX call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to send a JSON response to the client but include in that JSON response the time it took to generate the response. That's kind of impossible, but you then approximate it by including the time it took to generate the response but excluding the time it took to generate the time it took to generate the response (more realistic).

I think the simplest solution would be:

```
$start2 = microtime(true);
$all = json_encode(array(iterator_to_array($cursor),$timeExecuted));
$end2 = microtime(true);
$result = ($end2-$start2);
echo json_encode(["all" => $all, "result" => $result ]);
```

However in the client side you now need to do:

```
success: function (data) {
     var all = JSON.parse(data.all);
     var time = data.result; 
}
```

You could also do some sort of botch fix which may or may not work like:

```
...
echo "[" . json_encode($result). ", ". $all . "]";
```

Then you can access result like:

```
success: function (data) {
       var time = data[0];
       var all = data[1];
}
```

Beware when you use the 2nd way. It's generally bad practice because of odd encoding issues that may come up. Here it should be ok because `$result` is a number, but in general, it's not the best solution.

Note: Don't forget to set content headers before echoing anything, this will tell AJAX that it received a JSON response and will parse it accordingly:

```
 header("Content-Type: text/json");
```

3rd solution which may or may not work (not tested):

```
$start2 = microtime(true);
$all = json_encode(array(iterator_to_array($cursor),$timeExecuted));
$end2 = microtime(true);
$result = ($end2-$start2);
header("Content-Type: text/json");
header("X-Encoding-Time: ".$result);
echo $all;
```

And in your AJAX:

```
success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
      var all = data;
      var result = request.getResponseHeader("X-Encoding-Time");
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. Would the `echo json_encode(["all" => $all, "result" => $result ]);` encode $all again then? I really need to avoid that because it takes a long time.

Comment: The 2nd code should work, though as I said, be wary.

Comment: @heatonhampus I've updated with a possible 3rd option but I'm not sure if it works. If it does then it's probably nicer.

Comment: Awesome, the third options works great. I will go with that one. Thanks you again.

Answer (score 0):

First use string Concatenation then explode the string when required.

```
    $start2 = microtime(true);
    $all = json_encode(array(iterator_to_array($cursor),$timeExecuted));
    $end2 = microtime(true);
    $result = ($end2-$start2);
    $output=$all."|".$result;
    echo $output;
```

Then you can separate the string as and when required using "|" as a delimiter.

```
$output_array=explode("|",$output);
$all=$output_array[0]; // JSON string
$result=$output_array[1];  // Time
```

I hope this will solve your problem.